# Make browser to open domain via http and not https for everyone

Tags: browser, ssl, https

I need a website to be open in http and not in https (the reason is that I use 3-party platform which does not support SSL for now). Initially, I had SSL but then removed it (to comply with that platform).

Now I see that http://newsletter.ivanovml.com works okay but secure version https://newsletter.ivanovml.com results in a warning. Moreover, newsletter.ivanovml.com redirects to https and not to http, and therefore results in a warning too.

Is it possible to make newsletter.ivanovml.com go to http://newsletter.ivanovml.com always and make all browsers to open the website via http and not https?

Comment: Which browser? Also keep in mind that if you are typing private information on any page on that site, you *do not* want it to be http!

Comment: One possible solution (depending on how much you have outsourced) is to simply set up the web server to transparently redirect HTTPS requests for `newsletter.ivanovml.com` to the HTTP version of that domain. For instance, in Apache, this can potentially be done with a simple `Redirect` under the HTTPS virtual host for `newsletter.ivanovml.com` as `Redirect / http://newsletter.ivanovml.com`.

Answer (score 2):

Security aside, the web server is telling the browser to redirect to https if it has not already. Normally these https redirects can only be disabled by disabling the browsers response to web server redirects.

To directly answer the question, there are a few options. Your third party platform will need to deny the redirects (likely not an option), you will need to contact the site owner or scrape their site for a private certificate (latter is likely more fruitful, but I suspect you cannot offer a 3rd party private certificate to your service), or you will need to find a (4th) party service to proxy and decrypt the site data. It is also possible that the website cannot offer http traffic when https redirects occur. I know HTTPD (web server program) has some pretty specific configuration to force HTTTPS OR DENY, so there may be literally nothing that can be done.

To better zero in on a solution for you, we will need to know what your 3rd party service is and your affiliation with the website is so we can learn the feasibility of several options.